# Strange terminal mode, bash's mistake?

Tags: linux, shell, unix, terminal, xterm

Recently my bash has often got into strange states I don't understand (debian squeeze system). For example, after starting a new `xterm`, `Control-l` prints "^L" on my screen instead of cleaning it. This happens with a "fresh" `xterm`, with `bash` as well as with `dash` (even `xterm -e /bin/dash`). Also, a `reset` did never help.

By contrast, after `ssh`'ing to another box, `Control-l` does what I expect.

Can somebody make an educated guess for the cause to this very odd behaviour to me (my Unix knowledge can't help out)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, I found it out. `set -o vi` was the culprit, as for bash. As for dash, it's just normal behaviour... Been a hard one.

Answer (score 0):

Check the `stty -a`output and the `$TERM` variable.  `$TERM` should be "xterm" or "xterm-color"

Comment: `$TERM` is "xterm". What should `stty -a` yield? (Sorry, long output in next comment...)

Comment: stty -a: speed 38400 baud; rows 24; columns 80; line = 0; intr = ^C; quit = ^\; erase = ^?; kill = ^U; eof = ^D; eol = <undef>; eol2 = <undef>; swtch = <undef>; start = ^Q; stop = ^S; susp = ^Z; rprnt = ^R; werase = ^W; lnext = ^V; flush = ^O; min = 1; time = 0; -parenb -parodd cs8 -hupcl -cstopb cread -clocal -crtscts -ignbrk -brkint -ignpar -parmrk -inpck -istrip -inlcr -igncr icrnl ixon -ixoff -iuclc -ixany -imaxbel iutf8 opost -olcuc -ocrnl onlcr -onocr -onlret -ofill -ofdel nl0 cr0 tab0 bs0 vt0 ff0 isig icanon iexten echo echoe echok -echonl -noflsh -xcase -tostop -echoprt echoctl echoke